# Display alert message in browser using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to display an alert message in browser using Node.js code. Here my code

```
app.post('/logon', function (req, res)
   {
      var user=req.body.userName;
      var password=req.body.password;
      if((user=='admin')&&(password=='admin'))
         { 
              //redirect to home page
          }
       else
          {
                //here I need to display a alert message in browser saying that invalid user name or password is wrong
           }
       ..........
```

Comment: You need to run client side code for that.

Comment: @FelixKling Is there any way to do that in server side like res.write or any other.

Comment: Well, you can send any response back to the client, but the actual `alert` call has to be executed on the client.

Comment: @FelixKling Fine. While I am using this code  res.write(alert("Please enter correct user name and password."), it showing [ReferenceError: alert is not defined].

Comment: Because `alert` doesn't exist in a Node environment. It's a function only defined in browsers. As I said, you have to call `alert` in a client side script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using **`ajax`** to send the user name and password to the node server, then you can do a

```
app.post('/logon', function (req, res)
{
  var user=req.body.userName;
  var password=req.body.password;
  if((user=='admin')&&(password=='admin'))
      //redirect to home page
  else
      res.send(500,'showAlert')
```

on the server and in the **`error`** function of the ajax on the client side, do

```
error: function(error){
          if(error.responseText == 'showAlert')
              alert("Please enter correct user name and password.")
```

Like Felix Kling pointed out, this needs to be executed on the client side.